# Windows restart after Env. Var. change?

Tags: environment-variables

When do I need to do a restart for my server to use a variables new value, or no restart necessary?
Is it OS version dependent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When environmental variables change, any process that starts after that change is in place will have the change. Running processes won't get the new change until after they're restarted.

Answer (score 0):

You could broadcast WM_SETTINGCHANGE message without restarting the processes.
More info here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20091124062536/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/104011

Check out powershell script which helps:
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSCI/1.0.4/Content/core%5Cutils%5CUpdate-EnvironmentVariables.ps1